# How bind rows in list of lists

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have used the following code to group in list and sublist the dataset I am working on

```
init = c('PQ', 'MG')
dir = c('com', 'set', 'rit')

list3 = NULL
for (i in files){
  for (j in init){
    for (k in dir){
      list3[[j]][[k]][[i]] = 
        if(str_detect(i, pattern = j) 
           && str_detect(i, pattern = k) == TRUE)
        {read_excel(i)}
      
    }
  }
  
}
```

It works fine, despite the fact that for each sublist I would like to have the dataset bonded per rows, instead of other sublist:

[image]

I mean, for example, for `com item`, I would like to have all the lists within it, will be stored as bounded in that unique **com list**. Is there something that I could correct for this in my code?

Thanks

**REPREX**

I have created something similar to my situation

```
setwd("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/my_folder")
library(writexl)

dir = c('com', 'set', 'rit')
init = c('PQ', 'MG')
inpst = c('_ele_', '_mel_', '_col_')


for (i in dir) {
  for (j in init) {
    for (k in inpst){
      write_xlsx(mtcars, paste0(j, k, i, '.xlsx')) 
    }
  }
}


files = list.files("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/my_folder", recursive= FALSE, full.names= FALSE)

init = c('PQ', 'MG')
dir = c('com', 'set', 'rit')

list3 = NULL
for (i in files){
  for (j in init){
    for (k in dir){
      list3[[j]][[k]][[i]] = 
        if(str_detect(i, pattern = j) 
           && str_detect(i, pattern = k) == TRUE)
        {read_excel(i)}
      
    }
  }
  
}
```

As it is possible there is a redundancy when opening, each sublists (I mean the three when opening the two main ones). How could bind rows in those files and make theme as the merged dataset obtained when opening each com, set and rit subfiles?

Comment: Try `rapply(list3, rbind, how = "list")`? This isn't reproducible so not sure if this will work/produce your desired outcome

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work, but thanks. Possibly I did not explain myself so well. When opening/calling the C item - for instance - it should return the 9 lists under this object extracted/bounded together. Do not if it is clear

Comment: It would be the equivalent to delete the final sublist

Comment: Ok - If you make an example dataset you will get much better, faster help

Comment: The reprex is added

Comment: would you adapt your question to the reprex nm1 nm2 or init dir vectors

Comment: Hope I have done it fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I modified slightly your code:

1. The order in your loop, so we can loop in files at the final nesting, and row binding the corresponding file `Condition == TRUE` in one `df`
2. creating `df` at the final nest and reinitializing it for each `K` and `J`

```r
library(writexl)
library(stringr)
library(readxl)
files = list.files(recursive= FALSE, full.names= FALSE)

init = c('PQ', 'MG')
dir = c('com', 'set', 'rit')
list3 = NULL
for (k in dir){
  for (j in init){
    df=c()
     for (i in files){
      if(str_detect(i, pattern = j) & str_detect(i, pattern = k) == TRUE) {
         df=rbind(df,read_excel(i))}
     }
    list3[[k]][[j]] = df
  }
}

str(list3)
#> List of 3
#>  $ com:List of 2
#>   ..$ PQ: tibble [96 × 11] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   .. ..$ mpg : num [1:96] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>   .. ..$ cyl : num [1:96] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>   .. ..$ disp: num [1:96] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>   .. ..$ hp  : num [1:96] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>   .. ..$ drat: num [1:96] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#>   .. ..$ wt  : num [1:96] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>   .. ..$ qsec: num [1:96] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#>   .. ..$ vs  : num [1:96] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#>   .. ..$ am  : num [1:96] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>   .. ..$ gear: num [1:96] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#>   .. ..$ carb: num [1:96] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
#>   ..$ MG: tibble [96 × 11] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   .. ..$ mpg : num [1:96] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>   .. ..$ cyl : num [1:96] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>   .. ..$ disp: num [1:96] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>   .. ..$ hp  : num [1:96] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>   .. ..$ drat: num [1:96] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#>   .. ..$ wt  : num [1:96] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>   .. ..$ qsec: num [1:96] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#>   .. ..$ vs  : num [1:96] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#>   .. ..$ am  : num [1:96] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>   .. ..$ gear: num [1:96] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#>   .. ..$ carb: num [1:96] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
#>  $ set:List of 2
#>   ..$ PQ: tibble [96 × 11] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   .. ..$ mpg : num [1:96] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>   .. ..$ cyl : num [1:96] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>   .. ..$ disp: num [1:96] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>   .. ..$ hp  : num [1:96] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>   .. ..$ drat: num [1:96] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#>   .. ..$ wt  : num [1:96] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>   .. ..$ qsec: num [1:96] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#>   .. ..$ vs  : num [1:96] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#>   .. ..$ am  : num [1:96] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>   .. ..$ gear: num [1:96] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#>   .. ..$ carb: num [1:96] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
#>   ..$ MG: tibble [96 × 11] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   .. ..$ mpg : num [1:96] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>   .. ..$ cyl : num [1:96] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>   .. ..$ disp: num [1:96] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>   .. ..$ hp  : num [1:96] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>   .. ..$ drat: num [1:96] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#>   .. ..$ wt  : num [1:96] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>   .. ..$ qsec: num [1:96] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#>   .. ..$ vs  : num [1:96] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#>   .. ..$ am  : num [1:96] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>   .. ..$ gear: num [1:96] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#>   .. ..$ carb: num [1:96] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
#>  $ rit:List of 2
#>   ..$ PQ: tibble [96 × 11] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   .. ..$ mpg : num [1:96] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>   .. ..$ cyl : num [1:96] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>   .. ..$ disp: num [1:96] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>   .. ..$ hp  : num [1:96] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>   .. ..$ drat: num [1:96] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#>   .. ..$ wt  : num [1:96] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>   .. ..$ qsec: num [1:96] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#>   .. ..$ vs  : num [1:96] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#>   .. ..$ am  : num [1:96] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>   .. ..$ gear: num [1:96] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#>   .. ..$ carb: num [1:96] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
#>   ..$ MG: tibble [96 × 11] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   .. ..$ mpg : num [1:96] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>   .. ..$ cyl : num [1:96] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>   .. ..$ disp: num [1:96] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>   .. ..$ hp  : num [1:96] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>   .. ..$ drat: num [1:96] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#>   .. ..$ wt  : num [1:96] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>   .. ..$ qsec: num [1:96] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#>   .. ..$ vs  : num [1:96] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#>   .. ..$ am  : num [1:96] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>   .. ..$ gear: num [1:96] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#>   .. ..$ carb: num [1:96] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>